# what is the best configuration to query a fullname in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup search analysis in Elasticsearch and I tried many combinaison without any success and now I don't know if it's possible :

Suppose I have 3 users with the following fullname

- John Doe
- Johnatan Lebus
- Jane Doe

Typing:

- `Jo` should gives **John Doe** and **Johnatan Lebus**
- `Ja` should gives **Jane Doe**
- `doe` should gives **Jane Doe** and **John Doe**
- `doe john` should JUST gives **John Doe** and not **Jane Doe**

Is the last case possible and what should be the configuration ?

Actually I have this :

```
 "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "keyword_analyzer": {
                            "char_filter\"": [],
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding",
                                "trim"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        },
                        "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
                        },
                        "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
                            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
                            "token_chars": [
                                "letter"
                            ],
                            "min_gram": "2",
                            "type": "edge_ngram",
                            "max_gram": "5"
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You probably want to look at a combination of n-gram and the standard analyzer.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely think you analyzer is probably fine for your use case, It's my suspicion that you need help at query time.

I set up my index using your analyzers, and make a field using it:

```js
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_analyzer": {
          "char_filter\"": [],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "trim"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
        },
        "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ],
          "min_gram": "2",
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "max_gram": "5"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "full_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then index a few documents:

```js
PUT test/test_doc/1
{
  "full_name": "John Doe"
}

PUT test/test_doc/2
{
  "full_name": "Jane Doe"
}

PUT test/test_doc/3
{
  "full_name": "Johnatan Lebus"
}
```

And then I use the following query for your last case, as an example.

```js
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_name": {
        "operator": "and",
        "query": "doe john"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Replacing the "query" field with any of your text above gets us the results we want. The real "solution" to your problem here is being a little more creative at query time, evern though it might not seem possible from a token perspective.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Ian, your helped me a lot ! You are right, I missed this part `"operator": "and"` I accept your answer but I have an other question, why `"query": "jo"` doesn't return anything ? What should I add to my mapping to return at least `John Doe and Johnatan Lebus`

Comment: @Smaïne Hm, that doesn't match my own results. I run the exact query as listed above, and I get both expected documents back. Is it possible one of the test documents wasn't indexed?

Comment: Your helped me a lo again with your small exemple (I tried it and It works) ! I think I have a problem with my original mappings and I with your help I'll find where does come from the mistake Thanks !